# I wrote a code but i think there is a better solution for my problem

Tags: c#

Any ideas how can I simplify my if statement code.

```
 for(int i=0; i<17; i++){
     tag[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
     if (i == 0)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 25;
                    }
                    else if (i < 4)
                    {
                        x += 40;
                    }
                    else if (i < 8)
                    {
                        if (i == 4)
                            x = 0;
                        else
                            x += 40;
                        y = 65;
                    }else if (i < 12)
                    {
                        if (i == 8)
                            x = 0;
                        else
                            x += 40;
                        y = 105;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i == 12)
                            x = 0;
                        else
                            x += 40;
                        y = 145;
                    }
    }
```

I think it can be reduced. These if statement they work all right but perhaps there are better way.

Comment: Which language - C++ or C#? You shouldn't have both tags, really.

Comment: Which language is this? It can't be more than one, so please don't spam with unrelated language tags.

Comment: As for your problem, if the code ***works*** (a hard requirement) then you could post on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead, but please make sure it's really [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there first.

Comment: I think it does not matter C++ or C#. I changed for C#

Comment: You can get rid of all those `if` statements by splitting your single `for` loop into multiple ones with the appropriate ranges

Comment: As said this site is not for working code. That said though you might want to take a look at the `%` operator in c#. All your `if` statements can be replaced by logic in a single `if ( i > 0 && i % 4 == 0)` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++)
{
    tag[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
    x += 40;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 25;
    }
    else if (i % 4 == 0)
    {
        y += 40;
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Might even be able to cut it down if we knew the starting values of x and y

Comment: Super. That it I wanted.   int x = 0, y = 25;